# How to Pass parameter to partiaView with return View(.....)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Iam totaly new mvc programmer and have some problem with my code.
From my controller calling/returning to a partial view like that..and its working: 
 Below is my code:

```
return View("~/Views/Partials/_CarModels.cshtml, new RenderModel(carsrent) );
```

I want now to pass a parameter color to partialview, i have tryed this and i get Error

`return View("~/Views/Partials/_CarModels.cshtml?color=red", new RenderModel(carsrent) )`;

What is worong ?

Comment: `return View()` does not make a redirect to a GET method - there are no query strings involved. Put a property for `color` in your `RenderModel` or assign the value to a `ViewBag` property which you can read in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this overload :

```
return View("~/Views/Partials/_CarModels.cshtml", myModel);
```

And add your `Color` property to `myModel`

For example :

```
public class MyModel
{
    //Your other properties

    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, in this example, `myModel` is an instance of `MyModel`

As mentioned above, you can also use [ViewBag](http://rachelappel.com/2014/01/02/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/) but in your case, the easiest way is to add a property to your model